# При добавлении библиотеки telebot, не видит атрибут TeleBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

[image: Вот сам код]

[image: Сама ошибка]
Всё делал по последней документации. Как исправить?

Comment: добро пожаловать на ru.stackoverflow. не все люди(роботы) знают этот фроймворк. расскажите что конкретно сделали? по какой документации? покажите историю команд в виде текста, а не картинки

Comment: И токен отзови и поменяй ещё.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, просто кто-то не умеет внимательно читать документацию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь:

a) У вас рядом нет файла **telebot.py**

b) Файл из которого вы запускаете скрипт не называется **telebot.py**

В данном случае наименование файла чувствительно.
Если не поможет переустановите библиотеку ручками, не через pycharm, используя pip3

Answer (score 0):

А вы уверены, что библиотека `pyTelegramBotAPI` у вас установлена?
Чтобы проверить установлена ли у вас эта библиотека необходимо написать в Терминале `pip freeze` .

Код на скриншоте у вас написан правильно.

Поэтому могу предположить, что, возможно, у вас не установлена библиотека, которую вы импортируете.

Comment: Если установлена библиотека, то попробуйте её переустановить